# Spring boot war package in tomcat webapps

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

My spring boot application.yml:

```
    server:
      port: 9999
    servlet:
      context-path: /test
```

and i put the war package in tomcat webapps
and my server.xml

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Context path="/" docBase="test" debug="0" privileged="true" reloadable="true"/>
    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
```

when i access the localhost:9999/test/index ,it does not work
What is the correct configuration?

Comment: what is the error that your getting?

Answer (score -1):

as far as I can tell you have to change the port of the tomcat if you want to run it as localhost:9999/test/index 9999 should be the tomcat's port on which the webapp will respond